# Where do ltsp user accounts need to reside?

Tags: server, login, ssh, ltsp

I've looked at the [fan club ltsp install articles](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-create-ubuntu-1104-x64-ltsp-server-32bit-thin-clients), but I cannot tell if the user accounts for my ltsp users need to reside only on the ltsp image.  I believe that is the case, and I've added them there, but when I update the image and try to connect, it's failing and it restarts and asks for the login again.  It's really wierd because I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to pull up a terminal and log in with the credentials just fine.

I'm trying to set up thick/fat i386 clients under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit.

Oh, another bizarre item-- I can login with my credentials under LDM on the ltsp client and it works fine.

Can someone tell me:

1. Do ltsp user acounts need to exist on the server?  If not, how does it map back to a home folder on the server?
2. Whats the relationship between the users and groups on the server with those on the clients?  It looks like the update image process does something with them.
3. Does LDM use SSH, and if so which SSH server is it talking to?  The one on the server or the one on the ltsp client?

Thanks.  I've googled my eyes out and RTFM'd until my head hurts.

Comment: Ok, so for #3 LDM does use SSH.  But still which sshd?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in LTSP thing, but since this question didn't get any answers I decided to write what I found out so far...

LTSP accounts should NOT exist in the ltsp image. They can be there, but this is not the correct way of setting up LTSP since you don't want to rebuild your image every time you add new user or change user password.

So, LTSP accounts should be on the server and whenever you login from LTSP client, you will see server account is automatically copied to client's /etc/passwd file

As to other questions you asked, I'm not sure myself.. Just learning this subject...

I'm struggling with LTSP authentication as well. Authentication works, but I can't enforce password policies.

Comment: that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Ltsp actually only boots the workstation , the workstation logs in to the root server after it boots , you modify user accounts exactly like you did before ..